# Does allocation of vector takes more time than primitive array in C++?

Tags: c++, vector

While solving a question on **codechef** I discovered a pattern and found that instead of filling the complete **n*m** array I can answer it just by building two arrays of **n*3 and 3*m** size. Hence I wrote it like:

```
    // #define REP(i, s, e) for(int i = s; i < e; i++)
    // 1≤ N,M ≤10**5

    vector< vector<int> > dp(n.size()+1, vector<int>(m.size()+1));
    REP(i, 1, m.size()+1)
        dp[0][i] = m[i-1]-48;
    REP(i, 1, n.size()+1)
        dp[i][0] = n[i-1]-48;
    up = min(3, (int)(m.size()+1));
    REP(j, 1, up){
        REP(i,  1, n.size()+1)
            dp[i][j] = (dp[i-1][j]&dp[i][j-1])^1;
    }
    up = min(3, (int)(n.size()+1));
    REP(j, 1, up){
        REP(i, 1, m.size()+1)
            dp[j][i] = (dp[j-1][i]&dp[j][i-1])^1;
    }
```

I got TLE on three of test my cases then I changed it like this:

```
    // #define REP(i, s, e) for(int i = s; i < e; i++)
    // 1≤ N,M ≤10**5

    int rp[ns+1][3];
    int cp[3][ms+1];
    REP(i, 1, ms+1)
        cp[0][i] = m[i-1]-48;
    REP(i, 1, ns+1)
        rp[i][0] = n[i-1]-48;
    up = min(3, ms+1);
    REP(j, 1, up){
        rp[0][j] = cp[0][j];
        REP(i, 1, ns+1)
            rp[i][j] = (rp[i-1][j]&rp[i][j-1])^1;
    }
    up = min(3, ns+1);
    REP(j, 1, up){
        cp[j][0] = rp[j][0];
        REP(i, 1, ms+1)
            cp[j][i] = (cp[j-1][i]&cp[j][i-1])^1;
    }
```

Assuming that **accessing** elements of vector and array take same time, does allocation and initialization time of vector what makes the difference? I couldn't make what makes my code to work.

Comment: The first code declares a single vector of vectors, and the second code declares two 2D raw arrays (it looks like they're C99 VLAs). If you want to compare vectors to raw arrays you need to express the otherwise *same* code with respectively vectors and raw arrays, and measure.

Comment: The first sample is valid C++ and the second isn't (use of VLAs - which may be a compiler extension).   The first also does a runtime check of vector sizes repeatedly in loops, the second doesn't.      In any event, comparing performance of initialisation when the two sections of code initialise logically different things is pointless.   The use of macros confuses things further.

Comment: `int rp[ns+1][3];` -- This is not legal C++, and is not a "primitive" array.

Comment: i also don't see how that could compile, but of course vectors will slow things down in some linear fashion.

Comment: Variable Length Array is only a part of GCC extension.

Comment: And, assuming Copy Elimination not presented (or moved in C++11), the first code will take a lot of time to copy a vector.